# C++ Function Prototypes really necessary?

Tags: c++, xcode

This is a question I've needed to find out for a while. Are Prototypes really necessary? I've heard a few people say they're quite useful, however I've heard a majority say they're a waste of time, or to be accurate, "useless".

So my question is, are prototypes generally useful? (especially when dealing with complex code). I only very rarely use prototypes so if they are helpful, please state how.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of prototype do you mean? Function prototype, product prototype, prototype-based OO programming, something else?

Comment: do you mean prototyping as developing a quick and dirty solution for a complex project to validate the risks and support.

Comment: With function prototype, a source file can be organized in a top-down order: callee after caller. People always want to read high level code first to see what the code does, then proceed to implementation if he/she wants to know more about how it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function prototypes are definitely useful (although not always necessary).

Imagine you have several functions that are very long and complex. You forget what the return type or parameter types are of one of the functions and need to look it up. If you have the prototypes for these functions in a header file and the implementation in a cpp file then you have much less code to look through to find out again.

There are other advantages but this is the main one for me.